# rsync and bash command substitution

Tags: bash, rsync

Trying to get a script to properly make use of variables.  (The below examples are on the command line but I see the exact same behavior when inside a `#!/bin/bash` script.

```
$ FLAGS='--rsh="ssh -2"'
$ rsync $FLAGS foo bar
rsync: -2": unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1084)
```

So then I add quotes.

```
$ rsync "$FLAGS" foo bar
```

And now it works properly.  Okay.  Now let's add some more flags to the `$FLAGS` variable.  (I tried it with just "-r" and just "-p", the same thing happens, so I don't think it's related to the particular single-hyphen flags I'm passing.)

```
$ FLAGS='-rptvlCR --rsh="ssh -2"'
$ rsync $FLAGS foo bar
rsync: -2": unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1084)
$ rsync "$FLAGS" foo bar
rsync: -rptvlCR --rsh="ssh -2": unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1084)
$
```

Notice in the second case it's treating the entire argument as a single option to rsync.

The basic command (typed out by hand without using the `$FLAGS` variable) works properly.

Any ideas?

Any ideas?  I've read through all the bash scripting docs I can find, and I can't figure out why rsync is ignoring the double quotes some of the time and treating `-2"` as a single token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw them into an array:

```
FLAGS=( '-rptvlCR' '--rsh="ssh -2"' )
rsync "${FLAGS[@]}"
```

See [this Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more detail

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. That FAQ is highly useful, too.